# How do I keep the datepicker field empty on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have 3 date pickers on my page and the selected dates are stored in the database. If the values are empty I want the field to be empty, but it shows today's date. I have used the below code,

```
jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker({
    startDate: new Date(),
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    setDate: ''

});
```

How do I keep the datepicker field empty on load?

Comment: which datepicker library are you using?

Comment: bootstrap datepicker

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a live demo? Because [I can't](http://jsfiddle.net/fqsfqvq3/1/)

Comment: Can you show the code of text boxes?

Comment: Below is my code

    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
  {
   $form->add_datepicker('','closing_date[]','text',$data['closing_date'][$i],'',5);
  } 

For the current case the first 2 datepickers have value whereas the third is empty

Comment: There are several bootstrap datepickers, and unfortunately they all work a bit differently.  Can you provide the link to the one you are using?  Also, can you edit your question to include the HTML for one of the datepicker inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
<input  type="text" id="example1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // When the document is ready

  $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#example1').datepicker();  
       $('#example1').val("");
   });

</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

onRender : This event is fired when a day is rendered inside the datepicker. Should return a string. Return 'disabled' to disable the day from being selected.

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

see "Disabling dates in the past and dependent disabling." section Example

Answer (score 0):

this May Help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#text_fied_id').datepicker();  
       $('#text_fied_id').val("");
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try leaving out the `startDate` in the datepicker options